# Why do I get 'unhashable type: dict' error when recursively cleaning json object?

Tags: python, json, dictionary, typeerror

I am trying to clean a json object by removing keys if their value is 'N/A', '-', or '' and likewise removing any of these values from any lists. Example of object to be cleaned:

```
dirty = {
    'name': {'first': 'Robert', 'middle': '', 'last': 'Smith'},
    'age': 25,
    'DOB': '-',
    'hobbies': ['running', 'coding', '-'],
    'education': {'highschool': 'N/A', 'college': 'Yale'}
}
```

I found a similar problem and modified the solution, giving this function:

```
def clean_data(value):
    """
    Recursively remove all values of 'N/A', '-', and '' 
    from dictionaries and lists, and return
    the result as a new dictionary or list.
    """
    missing_indicators = set(['N/A', '-', ''])
    if isinstance(value, list):
        return [clean_data(x) for x in value if x not in missing_indicators]
    elif isinstance(value, dict):
        return {
            key: clean_data(val)
            for key, val in value.items()
            if val not in missing_indicators
        }
    else:
        return value
```

But I get the unhashable type: dict error from the dictionary comprehension:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-79-d42b5f1acaff> in <module>
----> 1 clean_data(dirty)

<ipython-input-72-dde33dbf1804> in clean_data(value)
     11         return {
     12             key: clean_data(val)
---> 13             for key, val in value.items()
     14             if val not in missing_indicators
     15         }

<ipython-input-72-dde33dbf1804> in <dictcomp>(.0)
     12             key: clean_data(val)
     13             for key, val in value.items()
---> 14             if val not in missing_indicators
     15         }
     16     else:

TypeError: unhashable type: 'dict'
```

Obviously something about the way I do the set comparison doesn't work the way I think it should when val is a dict. Can anyone enlighten me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At first glance, this looks like a problem:

```
if val not in missing_indicators
```

When you use `in` on a `set`, it will check if the value you're asking about is among the `set` entries. To be a key in a `dict` or a member of a `set` in Python, the value you're using must be *hashable*. You can check if a value in Python is hashable by running `hash` on it:

```
>>> hash(1)
1
>>> hash("hello")
7917781502247088526
>>> hash({"1":"2"})
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: unhashable type: 'dict'
```

In your snippet, it looks like `val` is a `dict` and you are asking Python if this `val` is one of the *values* present in the `set`. In response, Python attempts to `hash` `val`, but this fails.

The hurdle you have to overcome is that *some* of the values in your outer `dict` are themselves a `dict`, whereas other values look like `list`, `str` or `int`. You will need different strategies in each case: check what type of thing `val` is and then act accordingly.

Comment: As a fix, you can change `missing_indicators` to be a list unless performance is absolutely critical. A linear search through a 3 element list is not big deal.

Comment: This works! Thank you. I get it now that val must be hashable for set operations -- changing missing_indicators to list type fixes the problem. I made an error in the post as well: doing the set operation manually also fails for the same reason. I will edit that part out.